# Cannot find module '@env' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, react-native

Why I get this TypeScript error message and how can I fix it ?

> Cannot find module '@env' or its corresponding type declarations

This occurs when I use this:

```
import { FB_ID } from '@env';
```

Tt should be named not @env, it should named 'react-native-dotenv' but in my config I named it @env so I can use it, and I can retrieve the FB_ID value. It works but I get a TypeScript error.

This is where I set the moduleName:

```json
      ['module:react-native-dotenv', {
        "envName": "APP_ENV",
        "moduleName": "@env",
        "path": ".env",
        "blocklist": null,
        "allowlist": null,
        "safe": false,
        "allowUndefined": true,
        "verbose": false
      }]
```

So how can I fix it ?

tsconfig:

```json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": ".", // this must be specified if "paths" is specified.
    "paths": {
      "@env": ["node_modules/react-native-dotenv"] // this mapping is relative to "baseUrl"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

- Create a `types` folder in your source folder.
- Create a file named `env.d.ts` in the types folder.
- Define your env variables as strings.

  ```js
  declare module '@env' {
    export const FB_ID: string;

    // other ones
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

You should probably look at the paths property of the compilerOptions of your tsconfig file which looks like something alongs the line of:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".", // this must be specified if "paths" is specified.
    "paths": {
      "@env": ["node_modules/<path to the module dist>"] // this mapping is relative to "baseUrl"
    }
  }
}
```

This will tell to typescript that @env point to the module and will stopped throwing errors about it. Otherwise it has no idea about the resolution of it and will only look for `node_modules/@env`

Comment: thanks for your answer but its not working, or should I restart my vs code ?

Comment: I am under jetbrains, when I update my paths it work just after the re-index., do you get the same error?

Answer (score 2):

I am using typescript and I've encountered the same issue

Step 1: Make sure you properly added the config in Babel config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    [
      "module:react-native-dotenv", {
        "moduleName": "@env",
        "path": ".env",
        "safe": false,
        "allowUndefined": true,        
        "blocklist": null,
        "allowlist": null,
        "verbose": false
      }
    ],
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
        extensions: [
          '.ios.ts',
          '.android.ts',
          '.ts',
          '.js',
          '.jsx',
          '.ios.tsx',
          '.android.tsx',
          '.tsx',
          '.jsx',
          '.js',
          '.json',
        ],
        alias: {
          '@app': './src',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Step:2
Create a types folder in your project
Inside that folder, create a *.d.tsfile, say, env.d.ts
in that file, declare a module as the following format:

```js
declare module '@env' {
  export const API_BASE: string;
}
```

You should add all of your .env variables inside this module.

Step:3 Finally, add this folder to the typeRoots field in your tsconfig.json file:

```js
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    // "baseUrl": "./src",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": [
        "src/*"
      ],
      "typeRoots": [
        "./src/types"
      ],
    }
  }
}
```